# Prevent Vim setting Application Keypad Mode on my VT520

Tags: terminal, vim8

I am attempting to use Vim via a serial console and every time I launch it, vim sends <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> and instructs the console to enable Application Keypad Mode and my numpad stops working.

How do I stop it doing this? I've seen multiple answers that say "just turn it off in the settings" but Vim keeps turning it back on again!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Do you have `$TERM` set to `vt520`? Or to something else like `xterm` or `screen` or `linux`or `vt100`? Please [edit] the question and include the output of `echo $TERM` (in your shell) or `:set term?` (in Vim). Thanks!

Comment: @filbranden Yeah I have everything (TERM, locale, stty etc) configured correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unsetting [`'t_ks'` and `'t_ke'`](https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html#t_ke) in your vimrc:

```
" Prevent Vim from setting application keypad mode.
set t_ks= t_ke=
```

If you'd like, you can do that conditionally, based on the `TERM=vt520` setting:

```
" Prevent Vim from setting application keypad mode on a VT520.
if &term ==# 'vt520'
  set t_ks= t_ke=
endif
```

These sequences are used by Vim to start and end "keypad transmit" mode.

Vim documentation also mentions those in [this help section](https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html#cs7-problem) and, in particular, recommend disabling them (setting them to an empty string) in cases where they cause trouble:

> Some termcap entries are wrong in the sense that after sending `'t_ks'` the
> cursor keys send codes different from the codes defined in the termcap.  To
> avoid this you can set `'t_ks'` (and `'t_ke'`) to empty strings.  This must be done during [initialization](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#initialization), otherwise it's too late.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I was away for a few days. That fixed it thanks, but I don't really understand why it was doing it in the first place? That help section doesn't explain it.

Comment: Sometimes it's a terminfo/termcap bug that lists these sequences for a vt520 even if they're not the most appropriate... Vim also has some hardcoded "guesses" of what will work for some specific `$TERM` settings, that it will for most part match by name... A VT520 is not really common these days, so it's not surprising to find it's not completely well supported!